# Where to find the details of Scala's type inference?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I want to understand how type checking/algorithm works. It's very complicated and there're a lot of cases. Is there any good tutorial/documentation for this (I am aware of language specification but IMO, it's too hard to read).

I simply want the details of how Scala's type inference works under the hood.

Comment: AFAIK, Scala [uses](https://twitter.com/odersky/status/193108721679867906) [Colored Local Type Inference](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/popl01.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not very complicated. A very concise description can be found in section 16.9 of Odersky/Spoon/Venners's book 'Programming in Scala' (1st edition; in the second edition I belief it is section 16.10):

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-lists.html#16.9

---

So if this is too basic, maybe the following paper helps you:

- Vincent Cremet, François Garillot, Sergueï Lenglet and Martin Odersky, "A Core Calculus for Scala Type Checking", in: Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 2006, Volume 4162/2006, 1-23, DOI: 10.1007/11821069_1 (Springer).

[You can find an accessible PDF version](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00903812/document) through Google Scholar.

---

Or you may want to look at the sources of Scala 2.12.x in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala.