# How to set type parameter bound in scala to make generic function for numerics?

Tags: scala, generics, types, implicit

I want to make a sum function that works with all Numeric types.

This works:

```
object session {
  def mapReduce[A](f: A => A, combine: (A, A) => A, zero: A, inc: A)
                  (a: A,b: A)
                  (implicit num:Numeric[A]): A = {
    def loop(acc: A, a: A) =
    if (num.gt(a, b)) acc
    else combine(f(a), mapReduce(f, combine, zero, inc)(num.plus(a, inc), b))
    loop(zero, a)
  }

  def sum(f: Int => Int)
         (a: Int, b: Int) : Int = {
    mapReduce(f, (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, 0, 1)(a, b)}
  sum(x => x)(3, 4)  //> res0: Int = 7

  def product(f: Int => Int)
             (a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    mapReduce(f, (x: Int, y: Int) => x * y, 1, 1)(a, b)}
  product(x => x)(3, 4) //> res1: Int = 12

  def fact(n: Int) = product(x => x)(1, n)
  fact(5) //> res3: Int = 120
}
```

but when I try to make sum generic like this:

```
def sum[A](f: A => A)
           (a: A, b: A)
           (implicit num:Numeric[A]): A = {
  mapReduce(f, (x: A, y: A) => num.plus(x, y), 0, 1)(a, b)}
sum(x => x)(3.0, 4.0) // should be 12.0
```

I get this error on f

> type mismatch;  found   : A => A  required: Any => Any

when i pass it to mapReduce. So what do i need to do to make sum accept any Numeric value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the other answer is almost correct except for the fact that the type has to be made explicit when calling `mapReduce` instead of when calling `sum`.

So in your generic definition of `sum`, you might want to do this:

```
def sum[A](f: A => A)(a: A, b: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A =
  mapReduce[A](f, num.plus, num.zero, num.one)(a, b)
```

That's however not enough for the typer to infer the concrete type of `A`, e.g. `Double` when calling `sum(x => x)(3.0, 4.0)`. The reason for this is that the typer is going from first to last parameter list, left to right.
Your first parameter list declares `f: A => A` and only the second parameter list defines `(a: A, b: A)`. Once the typer reaches the end of the first parameter list, it doesn't know what `A` exactly is, and hence it fixes the type of `A` to some "abstract" `A`. The only thing that it knows about `A` at this point is that it is a subtype of `Any`.
When the typer then gets to the second parameter list, it could theoretically infer `A` as `Double` or whatever your concrete type is, but as said before the type has already been fixed. This is just a flaw of Scala's typer which can easily be circumvented once you get the hang of it.
More precisely, all you have to do is help the typer by switching the first and second parameter lists like so:

```
def sum[A](a: A, b: A)(f: A => A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A =
  mapReduce[A](f, num.plus, num.zero, num.one)(a, b)
```

Then it's possible to call `sum` without being explicit about the type, e.g.

```
Console println sum(3.0, 4.0)(x => x)     // 7.0
```

Comment: is this a bug or a design flaw of scala's typer?

Comment: It's a feature ;-) This issue has been around for a long while and I think it also will be. I'm not exactly sure which type inference algorithm is used, but it's definitely not Hindley-Milner. Could be there's more to find out starting from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11274375/271678).

Answer (score 0):

Give the type of `sum` explicitly. I have already provided an answer to a similar question in

[A simple foldRight type issue in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445659/a-simple-foldright-type-issue-in-scala/20446394#20446394).

Questions are totally different but the reason is exactly the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer please answer it rather than posting link

Comment: how do I do this and how is this supposed to help? I want sum to infer the types from the values it gets.

Comment: Check out the answer that @tiran linked to. It's a matter of the scala typer which goes from left to right and (generally speaking) infers your `A` a little too early (from the first argument list). Call `sum[Double]` or `sum[Int]`, i.e. make the type explicit on the call site, that should do the trick.

Comment: I get the same error when i do this `sum[Double](x => x)(3.0, 4.0)` or this `sum[Int](x => x)(3, 4)`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Instead, make the type explicit when calling `mapReduce`, for example: `def sum[A](f: A => A)(a: A, b: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A =
    mapReduce[A](f, num.plus, num.zero, num.one)(a, b)`.

Comment: @fotNelton okay, this works but now I have to specify the type parameter when i call sum. It does not infer the type from the values I provide. It even takes integer when i provide Double as type parameter `sum2[Int](x => x)(3, 4)     //> res3: Int = 7
 sum2[Double](x => x)(3, 4)  //> res4: Double = 7.0`

Comment: That's exactly because of what is meant by the typer going from left to right. Your first argument list is `(f: A => A)`, and only from the second argument list `(a: A, b: A)` the typer could infer what `A` really is. But when it comes to the second list it has already fixed the type `A` to some "abstract" `A` (hence `Any` since it doesn't know anything about that "abstract" `A`). Go ahead and switch the argument lists of `sum`, and you'll see it works right away: `def sum[A](a: A, b: A)(f: A => A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = mapReduce[A](f, num.plus, num.zero, num.one)(a, b)`

Comment: Since we've had a lot of discussion here, I've written this as a complete answer. HTH!